# Detect NO KEY PRESSES with keyboard module python

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

I'm making a tkinter program and want to detect a key press and do something when there is, however if no key is pressed the keyboard.read_key() will not execute and not let any other code run until a key is pressed.

Is there an alternative I can use or a way to check if no key was pressed?

```
def on_press():
    global running
    global turn

    if keyboard.read_key() == 'q':
        ws.destroy()
    elif keyboard.read_key() == 'a':
        if turn:
            print('turning off')
            running = False
            turn = False

        else:
            print('turning on')
            running = True
            turn = True
            start()
    else:
        start()

def start():
    global running
    global turn
    print('start')
    if running:
        print('clicking')
        mouse.click(Button.left, cps_val)
        time.sleep(1)
        on_press()
    on_press()
```

Comment: it makes no sense - key is `not pressed` millions times in every second - so it would have to run it millions times. Can't you run it manually at the beginning?

Comment: if you want to detect key press when tkinter's window is focused then you could use `root.bind('q', ws.destroy)` without using `keyboard`.

Comment: `keyboard` can use `keyboard.add_hotkey('q', ws.destroy)` and it doesn't need to run `on_press()`

Comment: you should rather run `click` all time in loop `while True`  and use `if running` to pause it. But all this may need to run in separated thread because it will block `tkinter`. OR you would have to use `root.after(1000, func)` to repeate `func` every 1000ms (1s) without blocking `tkinter`

Comment: Why are you using the keyboard module? Tkinter has event processing at its core. Are you trying to detect key presses outside of your app?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I'm tring to detect key presses outside the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key is `no pressed` for the most of the time. Because computer is fast and human is slow so I would assumed that that key is `no pressed` at the beginnig and I would run code at once (without checking if it `no pressed`). And I would run "clicking code" all time in `while` at the beginning and I would use keys only to pause this loop (key `a`) or exit this loop (key `q`) - without checking if key is `no pressed`.

```
import keyboard
#import mouse
import time

# --- functions ---

def pause():
    global turn

    if turn:
        print('turning off')
        turn = False
    else:
        print('turning on')
        turn = True

def finish():
    global running
    
    running = False

def main():
    global counter
    
    print('start')

    while running:
        if turn:
            counter += 1
            print('clicking', counter)
            #mouse.click(Button.left, cps_val)
            time.sleep(1)
            
# --- main ---

turn = True
running = True

counter = 0

keyboard.add_hotkey('q', finish)
keyboard.add_hotkey('a', pause)

main()
```

---

If it has to run with `tkinter` then `while` loop  will block `tkinter` (`tkinter` will freeze because it will have no time to get key/mouse events from system, send them to widgets, update widgets, and redraw widgets in window).

I would use `tkinter.after(milliseconds, function)` instead of `sleep()` and `while` and `tkinter` will have time to work.

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard
#import mouse
import time

# --- functions ---

def pause():
    global turn

    if turn:
        print('turning off')
        turn = False
    else:
        print('turning on')
        turn = True

def finish():
    global running
    
    running = False
    
    root.destroy()

def main():
    print('start')
    
    loop()                   # run first time at once
    #root.after(1000, loop)  # run first time after 1s

def loop():
    global counter
    
    if turn:
        counter += 1
        #print('clicking', counter)
        label['text'] = f'clicking {counter}'
        #mouse.click(Button.left, cps_val)
        
    if running:
        root.after(1000, loop)  # run again after 1s
          
        
# --- main ---

turn = True
running = True

counter = 0

keyboard.add_hotkey('q', finish)
keyboard.add_hotkey('a', pause)

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='clicking 0')
label.pack()

main()

root.mainloop()
```